# Error in yocto meta-udoo build. Krogoth branch

Tags: build, embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake, imx6

I'm running a clean build of meta-udoo krogoth branch. Following is the bblayers.conf file

```
LCONF_VERSION = "6"

BBPATH = "${TOPDIR}"
BSPDIR := "${@os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(d.getVar('FILE', True)) + '/../..')}"

BBFILES ?= ""
BBLAYERS = " \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/poky/meta \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/poky/meta-yocto \
  \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-oe \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-multimedia \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-python \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-networking \
  \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-fsl-arm \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-fsl-arm-extra \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-fsl-demos \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-udoo \
"
```

I keep getting this error everytime i try to build. I've cleaned the directory and tried fresh builds with the isssue persisting.

```
ExpansionError: Failure expanding variable PATH[:=], expression was ${@os.path.dirname(bb.utils.which(d.getVar('PATH'),'bitbake'))}:${HOSTTOOLS_DIR} which triggered exception TypeError: getVar() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a mismatch between the `poky` version you're using and the one `meta-udoo` was made for.

You need to either use the branch of `meta-udoo` with the name corresponding to the `poky` version you're using, either fix all the instances of `getVar()` manually.